# Proof Question. Set, Relation and Function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, logarithms

A child plays the following game with a calculator. He types an integer n at random and repeatedly
presses the “square root” button, computing $\sqrt{n},\sqrt{\sqrt{n}},\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{n}}}$, and so on. The calculator has
a numerical precision $e$ (with $e\gt 0$ and $e \lt 1$) so that every real number $x$ between $1$ and $1 + e$
appears as 1 on the display of the calculator. Show that the child will see the number 1 on the
display after pressing the square root button for $\Theta(\log (\log n) + \log (\frac{1}{e}) )$ times, where log denotes the
logarithm in base 2

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Hints:  $\log\left(\sqrt{x}\right) = \frac12 \log(x)$  and $\log(e) = - \log(1/e)$

Comment: I am sorry but I really don't know how to proceed.
Can you please give me 2-3 baby steps and I will try myself taking it forward.